# Linking to an External Folder of Shortcuts in Windows 8.1 Start Menu

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, start-menu, start-screen

I'm trying to add a folder to my start screen using symbolic links. I can't seem to get any linked folders to show up. Here is what I tried first:

```
cd "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"
mklink /D "Web" "C:\Google Drive\Settings\Windows 8\Programs\Web"
```

Where C:\Google Drive\Settings\Windows 8\Programs\Web looks like this:

[image]

After restarting the computer those links do not show up in my start menu.

I then deleted the symlink and then tried this:

```
cd "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"
mklink /J "Web" "C:\Google Drive\Settings\Windows 8\Programs\Web"
```

The junction link didn't work either.

My heart tells me it must be a permissions issue. Can anybody help?

EDIT: I tried changing the permissions on the folder to make the owner of the folder in Google Drive to "SYSTEM", but it didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

See the blog
[How are shortcuts created and managed on the Windows 8 Start screen?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amar/archive/2013/03/07/how-are-shortcuts-created-and-managed-on-the-windows-8-start-screen.aspx).
I don't have Windows 8, but the example in the blog puts the shortcuts in a sub-folder
in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`. You might also try
using a sub-folder.

If symlinks/junctions do not work, you could use shortcuts to them instead.
Or put the symlink somewhere else and right-click it and use "Pin to Start" ([link](http://heresthethingblog.com/2013/02/27/windows-8-tip-pin-people-folders/)).

As another note: Try using mklink in a Command Prompt that is Run as Administrator.